# Android test for Launching activity of Another app

Tags: android, unit-testing, functional-testing

In my App, I have a list view that shows all the currently installed apps in the system. Clicking on an item will select the next activity (one of the installed apps) to be launched.

I am trying to add a Activity Test for testing that this happens.  I have an expandable list view that holds the list of installed apps.

```
// Get the child view of the list item that we want to launch
final View v = mExpListData.getChildView(0, launched_app_pos, false, null, null);   
assertNotNull("Child List View Null", v); 

mActivity.runOnUiThread(
                  new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // Click and launch temple run 
                        mExpList.requestFocus();

                    } 
                  } 
                ); 
        getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();


        TextView title = (TextView)v.
                findViewById(com.example.demo.R.id.apkname);
        assertNotNull("Title null", title);

        assertEquals("App Name not correct", "Angry Birds", title.getText()); 
        final int view_pos = 9;

        mActivity.runOnUiThread(
                  new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // Click and launch temple run 
                        mExpList.performItemClick(v, view_pos, view_pos);
                    } // end of run() method definition
                  } // end of anonymous Runnable object instantiation
                ); // end of invocation of runOnUiThread
        getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();

Intent launchIntent =    
mActivity.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(selectedApp.getPackageName());

// HOW TO I ADD A ACTIVITY MONITOR THAT WILL WAIT FOR THE ACTIVITY TO BE LAUNCHED
```

Any ideas?

I have added this as suggested below - still doesnt work

```
launchIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

ActivityMonitor mAppActivityMonitor = new ActivityMonitor(intentFilter, null, false);
mAppActivityMonitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout(TIMEOUT);
assertEquals(1, mAppActivityMonitor.getHits());
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set the action call intent.setAction(android.intent.action.MAIN);

Comment: Edited the post and added what you suggested. Is this what you are referring to?