# How to access child view of expandable listview dynamically?

Tags: android, junit, expandablelistview, testcase, expandablelistadapter

I want to get child view which is expanded.
In BaseExpandableListAdapter, have getChildView() override method. But i want to access this method out side the another class. how can i do this???

I have used below code to get child view. But can't get it.

```
        final LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) newCalibrationActivity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.items_newcalibration_child_3,
                expandableListView, false);

        AutoCompleteTextView mAcTxtCarName = (AutoCompleteTextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.actxt_car_name);
        AutoCompleteTextView mAcTxtModelNumber = (AutoCompleteTextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.actxt_model_number);
        EditText mEdTxtLicencePlate1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_licence_plate_1);
        EditText mEdTxtLicencePlate2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_licence_plate_2);
        EditText mEdTxtLicencePlate3 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_licence_plate_3);
        AutoCompleteTextView mAcTxtOdometerValue = (AutoCompleteTextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.actxt_odometer_value);
        AutoCompleteTextView mAcTxtReportingCode = (AutoCompleteTextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.actxt_reporting_code);
        final NewCalibrationAdapter calibrationAdapter = new NewCalibrationAdapter(
                newCalibrationActivity, calibrationDetails);

        final NewCalibrationAdapter calibrationAdapter = new NewCalibrationAdapter(
                newCalibrationActivity, calibrationDetails);
        final View expandedView = calibrationAdapter.getChildView(2, 0, true, view,
                expandableListView);
        assertSame(view, expandedView);
```

Comment: I have been founded solution using below link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469778/android-test-for-launching-activity-of-another-app

Comment: Cannot really locate the answer. Could you help?